# Facebook Wall vs Timeline

Tags: facebook

How do I post a picture onto my Facebook personal profile wall for a public audience, without Facebook also putting it on the timeline and notifying all my friends that I have posted a picture?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to publicly post a photo on Facebook and have it hidden from the timeline feed.

A possible work around to minimize the timeline exposure is to post it privately, then a week or so later make it public. Because it is old Facebook's algorithms may not show not as broadly, but no guarantee.